# Can I pass a certain value to member constructor based on template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is a simplified version of a class template (it has subclasses) that I have:

```
template<class T>
class Bitmap
{
public:
  typedef T pixeltype;
  Bitmap(const T* PixelData) : Data(/* PixelFormat enum based on T */) { ... }
  virtual ~Bitmap() { ... }
  ...
protected:
  Texture Data;
};
```

The template argument `T` to `Bitmap` can be either class `A<X>` or `A<Y>` (possibly a few more in the future), where `A` is a class template as well. Based on `T`, aka `pixeltype`, I need to pass one of the enum values `PixelFormatX` or `PixelFormatY` to the constructor of `Data`, which takes an `int`.

Is this possible? If not, how could I go about implementing what I described?

For completeness, here's what the subclasses basically look like:

```
template<class T>
class ColorizableBitmap : public Bitmap<T>
{
public:
  typedef T pixeltype;
  ColorizableBitmap(const T* PixelData) : Bitmap<T>(PixelData) { ... }
  ...
};
```

Comment: Could you do something like `T::getPixelFormat()` where getPixelFormat() was a static function?

Comment: Can't you use something like `if(typeid(T) == typeid(X)){...}` ? You need run-time type info for that and it's not very pretty but it should work. And yeah, sorry, you would also need to change the Data constructor since you cannot do an `if()` before calling `Data()`...

Comment: Or define a traits class that is passed as a second template parameter and specialize it on the first parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally use a traits struct for that:

```
template<class T>
struct BitmapTraits
{
};

template<class T, class traits = BitmapTraits<T> >
class Bitmap
{
public:
  typedef T pixeltype;
  Bitmap(const T* PixelData) : Data(traits::PixelFormat) { ... }
  virtual ~Bitmap() { ... }
  ...
protected:
  Texture Data;
};
```

Then use template specialization to define the traits of each class:

```
template<>
struct BitmapTraits< A<X> >
{
    static const int PixelFormat = PixelFormatX;
};

template<>
struct BitmapTraits< A<Y> >
{
    static const int PixelFormat = PixelFormatY;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
enum A {
  x,y
};

class X {
public:
  static A a;
};

class Y {
public:
  static A a;
};

A X::a = x;
A Y::a = y;

template <class T>
class Bitmap {
public:
   Bitmap(): Data(T::a) {
   }
A Data;
};
```

**Edited:**
In that case you could do something like:

```
enum A {
  x,y
};

template <const A V>
class X {
public:
  static A a;
};

template <const A V>
A X<V>::a = V;

template <class T>
class Bitmap {
public:
   Bitmap(): Data(T::a) {
   }
A Data;
};

int main() {
    Bitmap<X<x>> b;
}
```

**Edited 2:**
If I undestrood you right you have two nested class now and still you can do something like:

```
enum A {
  x,y
};

template <typename T>
class B {
public:
   typedef T t;
};

template <const A V>
class X {
public:
  static A a;
};

template <const A V>
A X<V>::a = V;

template <class T>
class Bitmap {
public:
   Bitmap(): Data(T::t::a) {
   }
A Data;
};

int main() {
    Bitmap<B<X<x>>> b;
}
```

The alternative is (as `Remy Lebeau` suggested) template specialization.